# Lebesgue Integral with Push forward measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{A}_1)$, $(\Omega_2, \mathcal{A}_2)$ be measurable spaces and $f\colon \Omega_1 \rightarrow \Omega_2$ be an $(\mathcal{A}_1,\mathcal{A}_2)$-measurable function. Furthermore, let $\mu\colon \mathcal{A}_1 \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a measure and define $f_*\mu =\mu\circ f^{-1}$ as the pushforward measure of $\mu$.

For every measurable $g\colon \Omega_2 \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ we then have

$\displaystyle \int_{\Omega_2} g\,\mathrm{d}\left( f_*\mu\right)=\int_{\Omega_1} (g\circ f)\,\mathrm{d}\mu$

My proof is as follows:

**Step 1**: Show the statement for $g=\chi_{A_i},\ A_i\in\mathcal{A}_2$ and $\chi$ is the indicator function ($1$ on $A_i$ and $0$ elsewhere)

$\displaystyle\int_{\Omega_2}\chi_{A_i}\,\mathrm{d}\left( f_*\mu\right)=\mu\circ f^{-1}(A_i)=\int_{\Omega_1}\chi_{f^{-1}(A_i)}\,\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_{\Omega_1}\chi_{A_i}\circ f\,\mathrm{d}\mu$

Here I used that $\chi_{A_i}\circ f=\chi_{f^{-1}(A_i)}$

**Step 2:** Show for $g=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\chi_{A_i},\ \alpha_i\in(0,\infty], A_i\in\mathcal{A}_2$, that is, for a simple function.

$\displaystyle \int_{\Omega_2} \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\chi_{A_i}\,\mathrm{d}\left( f_*\mu\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\int_{\Omega_2}\chi_{A_i}\,\mathrm{d}\left( f_*\mu\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\int_{\Omega_1}\left( \chi_{A_i}\circ f\right)\,\mathrm{d}\mu\\
\displaystyle =\int_{\Omega_1}\left ( \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \chi_{A_i}\right)\circ f\,\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_{\Omega_1}\left (g\circ f\right)\,\mathrm{d}\mu$

In the second equality I used Step 1 and in the third I used that $\chi_{A_i}\circ f$ is again a simple function.

**Step 3:** Show the statement for the $g$ as stated at the top. Since $g$ is measurable, there exists a sequence of simple functions $g_n$ which is monotonically increasing to $g$.

$\displaystyle \int_{\Omega_2}g\,\mathrm{d}\left(f_*\mu\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\Omega_2}g_n\,\mathrm{d}\left(f_*\mu\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\Omega_1}g_n\circ f\,\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_{\Omega_1}g\circ f\,\mathrm{d}\mu$

In the first equality I used the monotonicity of the Lebesgue Integral for simple functions (already proved in my book). In the second inequality I am not sure if my argument is correct. I used that $g_n\circ f$ converges monotonically to $g\circ f$. Is this correct? I know that $g_n\circ f$ is again a step function, but I am unsure if it indeed converges to $g\circ f$.

Comment: Your proof is fine, I think. If $g_n(x)\to g(x)$ for every $x$ then also $g_n(f(y))\to g(f(y))$ for every $y$ (concerns your last doubt). You could add a fourth step to prove it for functions $g:\Omega_2\to[-\infty,\infty]$ with the property that at least one of the nonnegative $g_+$ and $g_-$ has finite integral.